# Arrow tips remain even with "no head" command sometimes

Tags: tikz-cd

In a tikzcd diagram, even if I put the condition "no head", I see the tip in the pdf after compilation in the vertical and horizontal arrows. However, I don't see this problem in diagonal arrows.

**Question:** How do I get rid of the arrow tips?

Sample code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\author{Work}
\title{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
        \[
        \begin{tikzcd}
a \arrow[r, no head, Rightarrow] \arrow[rd, no head, Rightarrow] & a \arrow[d, no head, Rightarrow] \\
                                                                 & a                               
\end{tikzcd}
        .\]
\end{document}
```

On compilation, I get the following diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `Rightarrow` you overwrite `no head`, i.e. important is sequence of options. In the following MWE you can see three options, how to draw your arrows without of heads:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\author{Work}
\title{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
    \[
\begin{tikzcd}
a \ar[r, equal]   % gives the same as "Rightarrow, no head"
  \ar[rd, Rightarrow, no head]   % nohead prevail 
        & a \ar[d, no head, Rightarrow] \\  % \Rightarrow prevail
        & a
\end{tikzcd}
    .\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, you can achieve desired lines style with single option `equal`.

Answer (score 2):

The @Zarko's answer is perfect! I use (off-topic) with the tag, `xy` package that have also the same tips of `tikz-cd`. The syntax is criptic, sincerely, but it is not very hard to understand. I'm using xy because it has not yet corrected the bug of the vertical line (at the begin and at the end of `no head` option).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix@R=2pc@C=3pc{
a  \ar@{=}[dr]\ar@{=}[r]& a\ar@{=>}[d]^{\quad.} \\
&  a 
}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The code `@R=2pc@C=3pc` adjust the size of the `R=rows` and of the `C=columns` in function of your tastes.

Comment: +1! ones I will o learn a little bit more about `xy` package :-)

Comment: @Zarko ahaahahah LOL :-)..Thank you very much. The code of xy package it is not very simple, almost for me that I have difficulties to understand the commands. But I have not understood the reason of the actual bug in the tikz-cd when you use the option no head, and because it is not has removed.